# How can I change the duration of the animation without interrupting it?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the following sample of code to spin (continuous rotation) an `UIImageView`:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *theAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animation];
theAnimation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(0, 0,0,1)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0,0,1)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(2*M_PI, 0,0,1)],
    nil];
theAnimation.cumulative = YES;
theAnimation.duration = duration;
theAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[self.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
```

Now I want to change the speed of the rotation (means different duration) while the animation is displayed. The simplest way is to stop the animation and create a new one. The problem with doing so is, that the new animation will start at 0 degree and this causes a ugly jump when the speed of the spinning view changes.

**How can I change the duration of the animation without interrupting it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the previous rotation then use that as your starting value when creating the new animation.

```
CALayer* layer = [self.layer presentationLayer]; 
float currentAngle = [[layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
```

For a little more in depth explanation as to why you should call [[self.layer presentationLayer] valueForKeyPath..... rather than [self.layer valueForKeyPath....... is explained in depth in the Core Animation Programming Guide. Since the rotation (transform) has already been animated you would need to check the values of the presented layer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html

Comment: This statement always returns `0.0f`. But this was something I've tried already.

Comment: How about the 2nd solution? This would save the previous state and allow initiating the animation from the previous value.

Comment: The problem with splitting up into multiple animations is (tried it too already) that there are visible delays when main thread is under load. Endless animations (like with `theAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;`) are always fluent.

Comment: Have you tried the following and applying the new animation on the completion? I've used this in the past and didn't notice "hiccups" in the animation

 + (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;

Comment: Yes tried it. On load of main thread the rotation isn't fluent. Also the change of the rotation speed isn't real time when using very slow rotation.

Comment: I've used animation blocks on completion to animate multiple types of transforms without bogging down the main thread. Is it a problem of the animation easing in and out? If so you can remove the easing.

Comment: No. When the main part of the animation is idling, it works well. But when running the app on older devices the animation doesn't work well when there are tasks running in the background.

Comment: I imagine cocos2d is out of the question? It was designed for this type of behavior but honestly I have been successful doing this type of transform using CA and CC2d

Comment: Also the delay is an important contra point for splitting up into multiple animations.

Comment: How does Cocoa2D implements it?

Comment: Try setting theAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards; and also theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

Comment: Try the other solution I posted. Change your delay by assigning a variable to it then run the animation again. This will begin the new animation at the current transform of your view.

Comment: This is still the same main thread based principe I want to work around. Restarting animation doesn't work well in my case.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to detect current angle so I can add it to my values array.

Comment: You already have the solution posted to find the current angle (existingTransform or f for the radian value). I thought the problem was starting a new animation from the previous angle and experiencing a small glitch? Using the last solution would begin the new animation from the previous rotation and should not experience a glitch. Have you tried running instruments to make sure this is the bottleneck? Perhaps there is something else hitting the main thread at the same time.

Comment: Another idea would be to assign the rotation duration a variable and then make the animation restart after every rotation using the completion to fire another animation. This way the duration could be manipulated and the duration would change on every rotation if the variable has changed it value. You could assign a UISliders value to a float or int to test this.

Comment: There is a couple of stuff do to at main thread. So it is not possible to use the main thread to restart animation. The preferred solution is the one I posted in the question. But it have to care about the current angle at the beginning. And `CGFloat rotationAngle =  [[self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];` always returns 0.

Comment: What about the other solution? CATransform3D existingTransform = [[self.view layer] transform];

Comment: Is always `<0000803f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000803f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000803f 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000803f>`.

Comment: Are you creating a property for this UIImageView and using that? I see self.layer which leads me to assume you aren't executing this from a viewController and rather from a UIImageView subclass. Have you tried self.YOURIMAGEVIEW.********** from your viewController instead?

Comment: The implementation is done from within an UIView Category which adds a `(void)spinWithDuration:(CGFloat)aDuration repeatCount:(CGFloat)aRepeatCount` method. It won't change anything when calling the same code from anywhere else.

Comment: CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

If this is returning 0 then make sure the view isn't null. This always should return a value unless something else is interfering with your transform on that object.

Comment: `layer.transform.rotation.z` is still 0. (http://www.sourcedrop.net/Sqa6287432a5d)

Comment: Manually set the transorm and then check it again. Something isn't setting the transform for the proper object from the sounds of it. Place this right before checking the value. view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.05);CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[view valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", angle); // 0.05

Comment: Inserting `self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.05);
    CGFloat angle = [(NSNumber *)[self valueForKeyPath:@"layer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"%f", angle);` outputs 0.05 as I would expect. But using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is not a Core Animation solution.

Comment: Hmmm, try grabbing your layer this way. CALayer* layer = [self.layer presentationLayer]; then using float currentAngle = [[layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

Comment: Looks like magic :D It works! May you update your answer for others? So they do not have to read this long comments line?

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it figured out! It's always the little 1 word solutions that drive you crazy in this field! ;-)